# How can I pass an array from a controller to a template?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to render array to twig file I am able to render variables but not array.

My php file :

```
  public function build() {

    $vid = 'Sectors';
    $terms =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')- 
 >loadTree($vid);
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
     $term_data[] = array(
      'id' => $term->tid,
      'name' => $term->name
     );
    }
    // echo "<pre>";
    //  print_r($term_data);
    //  die;
    // return $vid;

  // do something
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'mdoner_custom_block',
      'title' => 'MDoNER custom Block',
      //'#test' => array('key'=>$term_data),
       'testmenu' => $term_data,
    );


  }
```

My array:

```
Array (
       [0] =>
          Array (
               [id] => 1 
               [name] => Climate Change 
           )
        [1] =>
           Array (
                [id] => 5
                [name] => Ecotourism
          )
    )
```

.module file:

```
function mdoner_custom_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'mdoner_custom_block' => [
      'variables' => ['title' => NULL],
      'test' => array(),
    ],
  ];
}
```

Twig file:

```
<!-- dump(content) --> // get array of all the content
{% for key, value in testmenu %}
  Key : {{ key }}
  Value : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I pass the `testmenu` variable to twig.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the `testmenu` variable to the hook_theme implementation, like this:

```
function mdoner_custom_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'mdoner_custom_block' => [
      'variables' => [
        'title' => NULL,
        'testmenu' => [],
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Then you have to pass it to the render array in your `build()` function like this:

```
return array(
  '#theme' => 'mdoner_custom_block',
  '#title' => 'MDoNER custom Block',
  '#testmenu' => $term_data, // #testmenu refers to the testmenu variable you set in hook_theme().
);
```

Now you should be able to iterate over the items in the `testmenu` variable like this:

```
{% for key, value in testmenu %}
  Key : {{ key }}
  Value : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```