# Array not displaying in twig template

Tags: 8, theming

Custom twig template is just this:

```
<ul id="rows">
  {% for product in products %}
    <li>{{ product.title }} <a href="{{ product.image }}">Image</a> {{ product.description }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

My custom module sends an array of products, which are something like this

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["title"]=> string(9) "Product 3" ["image"]=> string(56) "/sites/default/files/2019-11/128px-Small_Storage_Box.png" ["description"]=> string(22) "Description 3" } }
```

And I am sending it from a controller like this:

```
return array(
  '#title' => t('Return products list'),
  '#products' => $products,
  '#theme' => 'return-products',
);
```

In my .module file I've defined hook as:

```
<?php
function return_products_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'products' => [
      'variables' => [],
    ]);
}
```

I know data is there in an array, it just doesn't go inside twig template. Even if I type some

Test it won't be shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass an array from a controller to a template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288247/how-can-i-pass-an-array-from-a-controller-to-a-template)

Comment: In your theme hook it must say `'variables' => ['products' => []],`.

Comment: @leymannx changing hook so it says `'variables' => ['products' => []],` doesn't help. Still thanks.

Comment: @Budala1 In your template, prob needs to be `{{ product['title'] }}`

Comment: @NoSssweat No it's not that, tried it now and before. It doesn't enter twig template at all since it doesn't display some basic <p> tag I write.

Comment: Return Array should be `'#theme' => 'products'` since that's the current name of your template file in `hook_theme()`. But the answer below is probably what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Several things are wrong here.

Your `hook_theme` must return:

```
return [
  'return_products' => [
    'variables' => [
      'products' => NULL,
    ]
  ]
];
```

Now you have a template called `return_products` with a variable called `products`.

In your controller you must then use `'#theme' => 'return_products',` instead of `'#theme' => 'return-products',`.

Then create a template in `mymodule/templates/return-products.html.twig`.

Notice how your theme name must be with `_`(underscores) when referred to in PHP, but the file name must be with `-`(dashes).