# Passing preprocess function variables to a template

Tags: 9

I am trying to include another template file with pre-process's theme hook variables in a template file but it failed. I checked theme debug and it does not include example's pre-process theme hook. Can you give me guidance?

I added `{% include 'example--p1.html.twig' %}` in the page--front.html.twig  file. The example--p1.html.twig file has one variable, `{{ test }}`. Also, I created a pre-process function that adds variables to a page template. The code is the following.

```php
function mytheme_preprocess_example__p1(array &$variables, $hook) { 
  $variables['test'] = 'please help';
  $variables['test_var'] = 'this is my second variable';
}
```

It doesn't appear in the example--p1.html.twig template.

Someone suggested using the following code in the page--front.html.twig file.

```
{% include 'example--p1.html.twig' with {'test' : 'this is my message'} %}
```

I then added the following code in the following files.

#### mytheme.theme

```php
function mytheme_preprocess_example__p1(array &$variables, $hook) { 
  $variables['content']['text'] = 'second';
}
```

#### page--front.html.twig

```
{% include 'example--p1.html.twig' with {'test' : 'content.text'} %}
```

It works as it shows the text message value in example--p1.html.twig and page--front.html.twig.

How can I pass pre-process function's text messages' variables to page example--p1.html.twig and then I can display all the variables if I include example--p1.html.twig to page--front.html.twig?

Answer (score 3):

Preprocess functions are part of a render setup that includes at least:

- [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/10) to register the template to Drupal.
- [`hook_preprocess_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/10) to preprocess template variables before it's handed to Twig.
- The twig template to represent the HTML of the template.
- Something that "builds" the interface using the above setup.

  - This involves creating a [render array](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/render-api/render-arrays) with `#type` set to the registered template's name to render the data using the template. Examples of this are field formatters, controllers, blocks, etc.

The general flow of a render is `build -> preprocess -> twig = HTML`

Essentially a long-winded way of saying *not all twig templates have preprocess functions*. Twig templates that are just "included" are not part of this mechanism and won't have preprocess function.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to build custom module to custom template and defined the variables in controller. However, it cannot get any variables from controller to template. I have read [link] (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288247/how-can-i-pass-an-array-from-a-controller-to-a-template) the article for passing variables to template namely example--p1.html.twig but it still doesn't work for me. I can get the controller page and get html contents but it cannot render the data from controller.

Comment: The following code is from sandwich.module 
```
function example_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'example__p1' => array(
        'variables' => array('items' => array(), 'title' => ''),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHTuXXfBs7Y) The example code just likes the above video "Developing a Drupal 8 module with a controller and custom template" but I cannot get the variables from controller and display them in my custom template.

Answer (score 3):

For your front page twig: page--front.html.twig -- you would want to add a variable in the THEMENAME_preprocess_page function.

Preprocess functions would essentially match what the twig is targeting -- page data. If your twig was for a node, then you'd want a preprocess_node.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(array &$variables, $hook) { 
  if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()) {
    $variables['some_variable'] = 'some value';
  } else {
    $variables['some_variable'] = 'a different value';
  }
}
```

And then I think your include just needs to do this

```
{% include 'example--p1.html.twig' with {'test' : some_variable } %}
```